# Windows 7 password entry box takes a while to appear

Tags: windows-7

I have done scans and other maintenance tasks and I can't seem to arrive on a reason for such things to happen.

Scans:

- Malwarebytes
- McAfee Stinger
- avast! Boot Time
- AdAware
- Microsoft Security Essentials
- HighJack This

I also ran SpinRite on level 4 and ran a RAM test. Everything returned nothing and SpinRite found no bad sectors.

Windows CHKDSK and System File

UPDATE: A couple errors that I seem to can't get a rid of after working at it for about 4 hours.

- The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service hung on starting. [ID: 7011]
- A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the eventlog service. [ID: 7022]

Comment: Can you take a note of the time of day, then check the application and system event logs for any errors during that time?  It may be hardware that is slow or failing to initialise.

Comment: Does it show up quicker going into Safe Mode?  Are you on a network? Does unplugging peripheral devices help?

Answer (score 0):

Event 7022 is EVENT_SERVICE_START_HUNG

According to [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349362%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) it should also list which service is failing.

(Format: `The FAILING_SERVICENAME_HERE service hung on starting).

If that is an old unwanted service (e.g. after you manually deleted itunes rather than uninstalling it), go to [Start] [Control panel] [Administrative tools] [Services] and disable that service.